# I am not able to login using MSAL angular . Please find issue details below

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-msal, angular11, msal-angular

[image]

> "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.1",
> "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.15.0",

```
this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
.pipe(
takeUntil(this.\_destroying$)
).subscribe(val =\> console.log('SUBJEECT', val));

    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        tap((status: InteractionStatus) => console.log('MSAL STATUS', status)),
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe((val) => {
        this.setLoginDisplay();
      })
    
      this.login()
```

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): BrowserAuthError:
> interaction_in_progress: Interaction is currently in progress. Please
> ensure that this interaction has been completed before calling an
> interactive API.  For more visit: aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors.

Comment: the first screenshot is unreadable. Can you upload a better image or just copy and paste the text directly?

Answer (score 1):

BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress:

- The above error happens when one entity (in our case    it is   `this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$`) is still running while other   entity(`this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$`) is trying to run.
  To rectify the error add the **await** keyword in front them.

The code will look like this -

```
   await  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
              .pipe(takeUntil(this.\_destroying$)).subscribe(val =\> console.log('SUBJEECT', val));
   await  this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
              .pipe(
                    tap((status: InteractionStatus) =>  console.log('MSAL STATUS', status)),
                    filter((status: InteractionStatus) =>  status === InteractionStatus.None),
                    takeUntil(this._destroying$)
                    )
              .subscribe((val) => {
                                    this.setLoginDisplay();
                                  }
                         )
    
    await  this.login()
```

refer the following documentation :

[BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress:](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/errors.md#interaction_in_progress)

[angular spa with sign in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code?msclkid=71e33523b3fc11ecb5eca1c4025ade75)

[MSAL for angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular)